colourful and achromatic colours - is there a better term?
Disclaimer: I'll subsequently use "grey" and "colour"; spellings "gray" and "color" are not excluded, I just don't want to list them every time. This question is not about those differences.
Colours are frequency mixes of visible light perceived with human eyes.¹
There are colours which have distinct biases on the frequency spectrum. Those are what people tend to think of when you say "colour".
Those where the frequencies are balanced are shades of grey; when strong, they're called whites, and the balanced absence is called black.
In some other languages, adjectives exist to tell these two groups apart. Examples: Slovenian: "pisane in akromatične barve" ; Czech: "barevné a achromatické barvy" ; German: "bunte und unbunte Farben".
The best English term I've found for the grey type of colour is "achromatic". But the counterpart to this I've found listed as "colourful", which doesn't feel fitting.
Are there better terms to name and differentiate those colours with, and without a spectrum bias? Preferably a matching pair.
¹ improvements to this definition welcome, but that's not the purpose of the question.

"Saturated" and "desaturated".

It can be argued that white (a mixture of all colours that is therefore 'uncoloured) and black (the absence of colour which is in essence 'uncoloured' ) are not 'colours' at all.

See the distinction between tint and shade in color theory, though the words are often thrown around carelessly in general parlance.

Grey can mean drab, and colourful can be garish. It depends on what you want to express, and the target audience. Can you provide an example sentence?

@DougWarren Photoshop has an option called "desaturate", which removes color, leaving only black, white and grays; I think the word "desaturated" is a good choice.

"vivid" (orange, green, magenta, ...) and "neutral" (e.g. gray, ivory...).

Of course, a more obvious counterpart to "achromatic" is simply "chromatic." MW lists, along with "of or relating to color," also "highly colored."

You might want to ask in [photography.se]. They deal with color processing and will know what terms they use.

Computer printer software often uses "gray-scale" for printing using only black ink or toner.

If you have terms in a foreign language, it can be useful to give them, to see how they are translated into English.

@StuartF good point.
Slovenian: "pisane in akromatične barve" ;
Czech: "barevné a achromatické barvy" ;
German: "bunte und unbunte Farben".

@DougWarren "saturation" is useful in a specific context, but - saturation of what, exactly? That's the word I am looking form.

Saturated would normally be understood to mean high saturation, i.e. 100% or close to it, while the OP is, as I understand it, looking for a term that encompasses all degrees of saturation greater than zero. Chromatic may not convey that meaning in every context, but it is likely to be understood that way when used in the proximity of achromatic.

Try looking at a color wheel with a grayscale on it. Yes, it is achromatic as it is a mixture of black and white.  There is chromatic grey (mixed with other colors) and achromatic grey. https://www.pinterest.com/pin/352617845820558594/
